# MongoDB database design good practices

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm new in MongoDB and I had always used SQL databases so I'm a bit confused. I'm creating a database for store training sessions in this way:

```
var SessionSchema   = new Schema({
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now },
  time: Number, //Time in seconds
  user: {required: true, type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

});

var ExerciseSchema   = new Schema({
    session: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Session'},
    movement: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movement'},
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
});

var SetSchema   = new Schema({
    repetitions: Number,
    weight: Number,
    rest: Number,
    timestamp: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
    exercise : {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Exercise'}

});

var MovementSchema   = new Schema({
    name:  { type: String, required: true, index: true, unique: true },
    material:{ type: String, required: true},
    muscles : [{
       name : { type: String, required: true},
       percentage : { type: Number, required: true}
     }]
});
```

So the question is, in an object oriented database this is a good desing o is better to keep all in only one big documment?

Note: Sometimes I want to get only parts of the data (May be my desing mor efficent in this cases ?)

Note 2: The Idea is tha a session is composed by exercises and this exercises have one movement and an arbitray number of sets.

Note 3: The movement documents are commun for all exercises.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In mongoDB its a good practice to avoid links between collections. It's better to even repeat some data than creating two collection and linking. mongoDB is very fast and effective working on documents. It offer  large possibilities to work around nested fields which is great to use complex schemas. PS: What I say are generalities, you have to inspire you from it but think about what's the most adapted solution to your specific case

Comment: In addition to the comments from Gregory, one basic principle for DB design in document databases is the _query_. As opposed to a relational database where you do storage first and query second, in a document db you think first about the queries you need to do, and then design the documents to match this. As a rule of thumb, try to have all information you need for a specific query in a single collection so that you can work with simple conditions (equal, lower, greater) and avoid joining or logical transformations in queries as much as possible.

Comment: @GrégoryNEUT  Following your comment I think that save session,exercise and set in the same document  will be a better aproach. Thanks.

Comment: @mtj  Thinking in the querys I believe that keep movement in a individual document and put all the others documents in one will be better. Thanks